Downloading from the arXiv site and uncompressing
When I want to download a math-paper I put out on the arXiv server, I get a file with filename "arXiv-xxxx.xxxx.tar.gz" and I'm having trouble "uncompressing" this file to get the original tex-file. I'm using a "Microsoft Windows 7" operating system.
Q: How do I uncompress such a file on this machine?
You find the arXiv server here:
https://arxiv.org/list/math.AG/recent
Here you find the "download page":
https://arxiv.org/format/2406.19366

See if 7zip will install on Windows 7, Google 7Zip

@VomitIT-ChunkyMessStyle - it did install. Thanks.
